# Convert string to a particular date format

Tags: java

I have a date in the format:`Thu- Mar 22 2012`.Its is obtained in a string variable date1.I need to convert the date in string variable to date format.I tried the below ccode but failed to parse the date;Please help.

```
DateFormat formatter;
Date formatted_date= null;


formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE-MM d yyyy");
try {
        formatted_date= (Date) formatter.parse(date1);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: There is a space missing in your format string, after the '-'.

Comment: there is a space between your "Thu- mar" and your format. "EEE-MM" typo?

Comment: I tried ,formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE- MM d yyyy"); But got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thu- Mar 22 2012
EEE- MMM dd yyyy
```

I think you need something like this

UPD: for date formatting:

```
SimpleDateFormat toStringFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy");
String formattedDate = toStringFormatter.format(date);
```

so `parse()` is for `String` -> `Date`, and `format()` is for `Date` -> `String`

Comment: formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE- MMM d yyyy");.It worked..Thanks.

Comment: One more doubt i have now...The parsed date is of the form "Thu Mar 22 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012".But how can i get it as Thu Mar 22 2012 itself,in a variable of type date?

Comment: well, if you will just use `formatted_date.toString()`, then you will get the date in this "Thu Mar 22 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012" form. However, you can use date formatter to output the date in form you prefer. I will update the answer.

Comment: Actually, i need to insert this date into mysql db which is having a column named:DATE with type 'date'.It shows error as 'Incorrect date value: 'Thu Mar 22 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012' for column 'DATE' at row 1 '.How can i modify the code to get it saved in mysql?

Comment: then you should read about `PreparedStatement` and use its method `setDate()`. But first convert your date to `java.sql.Date`

Comment: sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(formatted_date.getTime());This one worked.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need three Ms 'MMM' to parse a months abbreviation like 'Mar'. And please check the whitespace after 'EEE-'.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to following format

```
EEE- MMM d yyyy
```

Note space after `-` and `MMM`

Answer (score 0):

If the already posted answers doesn't work then you surely have a problem with the locale. Try the following `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE- MMM d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thank  With the given mode and given the locale's default date format symbols constructor SimpleDateFormat. Note: This constructor may not support all locales. To cover all the language environment

```
public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern,Locale locale)
   //local:Locale.ENGLISH
   //default is not English
   formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
   try {
        formatted_date= (Date) formatter.parse("Wed, Jul 4, '01");
   } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```